# Writing nonlinear ODE in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to obtain the eigenvalues of the following nonlinear system

${\displaystyle {\dot {x}}_{1}(t)=x_{2}(t)}$

$  {\displaystyle{\dot {x}}_{2}(t)=-{\frac {g}{\ell }}\sin {x_{1}}(t)-{\frac {k}{m\ell }}{x_{2}}(t)}$

I have tried to convert to matrix form in order to find $A-I\lambda$

$A= [0, 1$

$-g/l\sin(x_1), -k/ml]$

But this doesn't seem right due to he sin term still being present, any advice?

Comment: I have calculated the eigenvalues of a similar nonlinear system to determine the stability and wanted to see how the introduction of a couple of nonlinear terms affetc this stability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally what you do is to linearize the system about an equilibrium point, and then calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Here, our vector field is $F: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$, defined by
\begin{align}
F(x_1,x_2) = \left(x_2, \,  -\frac{g}{l} \sin(x_1) - \frac{k}{ml}x_2  \right).
\end{align}
An equilibrium point is one where $F$ vanishes. It is easy to see that $F(0,0) = (0,0)$, so the origin is an equilibrium point. Now, let's compute the Jacobian matrix of $F$ at the origin:

\begin{align}
JF_{(0,0)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-\frac{g}{l} & -\frac{k}{ml}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
So, you can consider the linearised system
\begin{align}
x'(t) = JF_{(0,0)} \cdot x(t)
\end{align}
where for convenince I denote $x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}$. Now, you can definitely compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $JF_{(0,0)}$.

---

You've been given a non-linear equation $x'(t) = F(x(t))$, so it doesn't make much sense to talk about eigenvalues of such a system. What you have done is to artificially (and incorrectly) "force" $F(x(t))$ into a product of a certain $2 \times 2$ matrix and the column vector $x(t)$, which conceptually isn't very meaningful.

On the other hand, what I suggested is (usually) meaningful near the the equilibrium point, because you're approximating the non-linearity of $F$ by its derivative, which gives you a simple linear equation to analyze. And in general, knowing the behavior of the linear system tells you the behavior of non-linear system near the equilibrium point.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand, can I just ask if the same method would work in principle for larger systems?

Also, is it surprising in a sense that the eigenvalues (and therefore stability) does not rely on k or m?

Comment: @MathsPro Yes it carries over verbatim, just replace $\Bbb{R}^2$ with $\Bbb{R}^n$ (but note that the origin isn't always an equilibrium point). So, in general if $F: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$ is a (for example) $C^1$ map, and $F(x_0) = 0$ (i.e $x_0$ is an equilibrium point), then rather than solving the (generally difficult) system $x'(t) = F(x(t))$, we solve the linearized model $x'(t) = JF_{x_0} \cdot x(t)$ to gain a qualitative understanding of the non-linear system.

Comment: Thanks peek-a-boo final question, if row 1 of A was 1,0 insteady of 0,1, I wouldn't have to linearise about sin(x) because the stability is now independent.

Comment: @MathsPro I'm not sure I understand your question. You wrote $A = \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 \\ c\sin(x_1) & d\end{pmatrix}$ (I wrote $c,d$ because I'm too lazy to write fractions). But if you multiply $A \cdot x$ you don't get the RHS of your ODE. Instead, you get $x_1' = x_2$ and then $x_2' = c \sin(x_1) \cdot x_1 + d \cdot x_2$

Comment: Ah Ok, thank you very much